# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start" is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to receive distances from my ultrasonic sensor but I the recieve the error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start' referenced before assignment." I tried adding `global start` but i just get another error: `NameError 'start' is not defined`

Code:

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep, time

DEBUG = False # debug mode?
SETTLE_TIME = 2 
CALIBRATIONS = 5 

CALIBRATION_DELAY = 1 

TRIGGER_TIME = 0.00001 
SPEED_OF_SOUND = 343 #
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 18 
ECHO = 27 
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN) 

def calibrate():
        print "Calibrating..."

        print ("-Place the sensor a measured distance away from an \
        object.")
        known_distance = input("-What is the measured distance(cm)? ")

        print ("-Getting calibration measurements...")
        distance_avg = 0
        for i in range(CALIBRATIONS):
                distance = getDistance()
                if (DEBUG):
                print "(--Got {}cm".format(distance))

                distance_avg += distance
                sleep(CALIBRATION_DELAY)

        distance_avg /= CALIBRATIONS
        if (DEBUG):
        print ("--Average is {}cm".format(distance_avg))

        correction_factor = known_distance / distance_avg
        if (DEBUG):
        print ("--Correction factor is \{}".format(correction_factor))
        print ("Done.")
        print
        return correction_factor
# uses the sensor to calculate the distance to an object
def getDistance():

        GPIO.output(TRIG, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(TRIGGER_TIME)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, GPIO.LOW)

        while (GPIO.input(ECHO) == GPIO.LOW):
                start = time()
        while (GPIO.input(ECHO) == GPIO.HIGH):
                end = time()

        duration = end - start

        distance = duration * SPEED_OF_SOUND

        distance /= 2

        distance *= 100
        return distance
########
# MAIN #
########
# first, allow the sensor to settle for a bit
print "Waiting for sensor to settle ({}s)...".format(SETTLE_TIME)
GPIO.output(TRIG, GPIO.LOW)
sleep(SETTLE_TIME)
# next, calibrate the sensor
correction_factor = calibrate()
# then, measure
input("Press enter to begin...")
print "(Getting measurements:")
while (True):

        print ("-Measuring...")
        distance = getDistance() * correction_factor
        sleep(1)

        distance = round(distance, 4)

        print ("--Distance measured: {}cm".format(distance))

        i = input("--Get another measurement (Y/n)? ")

        if (not i in [ "y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "YES", "" ]):
                break

print ("Done.")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Shell

```
Waiting for sensor to settle(2s)...
Calibrating...
-Place sensor a measured distance away from an \ object
-What is themeasure distance(cm)?5
-Getting calibration measurements...
```

Error

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Program5.py", line 87, in <module>
    correction_factor = calibrate()
  File "/home/pi/Program5.py", line 33, in calibrate 
    distance = getDistance()
  File "/home/pi/Program5.py", line 69, in getDistance
    duration = end-start

UnboundLcalError: local variable 'start' reference dbefore assignment.
```

Comment: Don't just randomly add `global` directives. Try to understand why that would actually be needed. You aren't trying to assign to global variable. The most likely explanation is that `while (GPIO.input(ECHO) == GPIO.LOW):` is false initially, so `start` is never assigned to. Not sure if that while-loop makes sense, but I'm not familiar with the library...

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you used `start` before assigning it a value. A quick search shows where you set it:

```
    while (GPIO.input(ECHO) == GPIO.LOW):
            start = time()
```

if `GPIO.input(ECHO)` isn't `GPIO.LOW` when you first enter the `while` loop, `start` isn't set. So, what do you want to do if gpio isn't low to start with? Is it an error? Should you go with a default?

```
    start = None
    while (GPIO.input(ECHO) == GPIO.LOW):
            start = time()
    if start is None:
        raise ValueError("bad gpio state") # better to make your own exception
        # or perhaps set a start time
        # start = time()
```